# Cloudformation stack references old/nonexistent resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, lambda-authorizer

My stack is referencing a resource that has been deleted (long story short it's been deleted because we use Serverless for API GW and async routes at the same time).

When I look at CloudFormation I see the resource and its ID. However the resource does not exist anymore. Is there a way to remove this reference or update it? Note that the new resource was created separately using AWS CLI, not through CloudFormation updates.
Here's an image to the resource I am talking about
[image]

This command `aws apigateway get-authorizers --rest-api-id` however does show the correct ID for the authorizer. It's the cloudformation console `Resources` tab that shows it outdated.

Comment: If it was not created by CFN, then how it ended up in the CFN template and stack?

Comment: @Marcin It was created at first with the CFN. However, CFN deleted these resources on update. It's related to using Serverless SAM and CFN at the same time. Once these resources are deleted we are adding them back using CLI. However CFN does not update its stack resources even if it deletes them.

Comment: What does drift detection on the stack show?

Comment: No drift. I don't see anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the handy `DefinitionBody` property under Properties. You can define your API Gateway methods, authorizer and other things using OpenAPI specification. Just include the correct syntax under that property DefinitionBody.

The way I found out my DefinitionBody was by exporting an existing API gateway  from the API Gateway console (API GW -> Stages -> choose stage and click on Export tab, choose Export as Swagger + API Gateway Extensions) and modifying it according to my needs. You can see the screenshot of this tab in my answer here: [Defining authorizer and using it in API Gateway using Open API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342603/defining-authorizer-and-using-it-in-api-gateway-using-open-api)

OpenAPI docs can be found here: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md